# Convert specific tab from an .xlsx file to Google Sheet (Google Script)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

im using this script on Google Script to convert an xlsx to a Google Sheet content, and this works fine, but i want to get only a specific TAB from an xlsx file, so where can i put this information in this code?

Thanks

```html
function myFunction() {
  // 1. Retrieve XLSX data.
  const url = "https://example.xlsx"; // This is your URL.
  const blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob();

  // 2. Convert XLSX data to Google Spreadsheet as the temporal Spreadsheet.
  const id = Drive.Files.insert({title: "Tesouro", mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS}, blob).id;

  // 3. Retrieve values from the converted Spreadsheet.
  const values = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheets()[0].getDataRange().getValues();

  // 4. Put the values from the converted Spreadsheet to the active sheet.
  const dstSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  dstSheet.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);

  // 5. Remove the temporal Spreadsheet.
  DriveApp.getFileById(id).setTrashed(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are able to select the sheet by:

```
getSheets()[0]//that's first sheet.
getSheets()[1]//that's second sheet.
```

or you can select sheet by SheetName:

```
SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName('sheetname')
```

// 3. Retrieve values from the converted Spreadsheet.

```
const values = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheets()[0].getDataRange().getValues();
```